# What does this verse mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, paraphrasing

This verse has been taken from the poem **In Spite of War**. What does it mean?

> My spirit still may light its flame.
> At that same torch whence poppies came.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about literary interpretation

Comment: What do _you_ think it means?

Comment: It looks to me like a homage to opium. Or maybe the "poppy" reference is to the poppies worn on Remembrance Sunday. People should make up their own minds with poetry.

Comment: Poppies famously grow in Flanders.

Answer (score 1):

[allpoetry.com *In Spite of War*](https://allpoetry.com/In-Spite-Of-War)

> My spirit still may light its flame
> At that same torch whence poppies came.
> Where morning's altar whitely burns
> Lilies may lift their silver urns
> In spite of war, in spite of shame.

The text of the poem mentions seven different flowers, which elate the poet "In Spite of War". The lines that immediately follow the one in question suggest that the "torch" is the morning sun. Its light makes the flowers grow, and dispels the darkness of war from her spirit.